# Elementary OS freezing randomly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, freeze, crash, elementaryos

I'm running Elementary OS Freya for a long time now, same install for at least 2 years now, and every once in a while it will just freeze up completely, not responding at all anymore, not just the desktop but completely, the only way to fix it is to hold the power button..
I had a problem with swap at first, but fixed that, and I've also installed the nvidia proprietary drivers, but none of those things seem to have fixed it.

It happened again just now, and thought I'd post a part of the syslog file, as I have no idea what I'm looking at here, I was hoping someone else could point out of there's an issue here..

Also, it seems to happen completely randomly

```
    Aug 21 13:15:34 Asus colord: Automatic metadata add icc-dc945c3592fc6c2089fd79db35a300dc to xrandr-LVDS1
    Aug 21 13:15:34 Asus colord: Profile added: icc-dc945c3592fc6c2089fd79db35a300dc
    Aug 21 13:15:34 Asus kernel: [   42.656869] audit_printk_skb: 48 callbacks suppressed
    Aug 21 13:15:34 Asus kernel: [   42.656874] audit: type=1400 audit(1503314134.828:28): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=2314 comm="apparmor_parser"
    Aug 21 13:15:34 Asus kernel: [   42.656883] audit: type=1400 audit(1503314134.828:29): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2314 comm="apparmor_parser"
    Aug 21 13:15:34 Asus colord: Profile added: M2020-Series-Gray..
    Aug 21 13:15:34 Asus colord: Device added: cups-M2020-Series
    Aug 21 13:15:35 Asus dbus[457]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.UDisks2' (using servicehelper)
    Aug 21 13:15:35 Asus udisksd[2385]: udisks daemon version 2.1.3 starting
    Aug 21 13:15:35 Asus dbus[457]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2'
    Aug 21 13:15:35 Asus udisksd[2385]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 on the system message bus
    Aug 21 13:15:39 Asus kernel: [   46.979071] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.GFX0._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
    Aug 21 13:15:39 Asus kernel: [   46.979166] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.GFX0._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
    Aug 21 13:15:39 Asus kernel: [   46.979239] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending console...
    Aug 21 13:15:39 Asus kernel: [   46.979243] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending display...
    Aug 21 13:15:39 Asus kernel: [   46.979254] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: evicting buffers...
    Aug 21 13:15:39 Asus kernel: [   46.979256] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: waiting for kernel channels to go idle...
    Aug 21 13:15:39 Asus kernel: [   46.979297] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending client object trees...
    Aug 21 13:15:39 Asus kernel: [   46.979533] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending kernel object tree...
    Aug 21 13:16:12 Asus wpa_supplicant[1005]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
    Aug 21 13:16:13 Asus sm-mta[1873]: unable to qualify my own domain name (Asus) -- using short name
    Aug 21 13:16:13 Asus sm-mta[1873]: gethostbyaddr(192.168.0.103) failed: 1
    Aug 21 13:16:13 Asus sm-mta[2633]: starting daemon (8.14.4): SMTP+queueing@00:10:00
    Aug 21 13:16:15 Asus sm-msp-queue[1882]: unable to qualify my own domain name (Asus) -- using short name
    Aug 21 13:16:16 Asus kernel: [   84.366042] init: plymouth-stop pre-start process (2771) terminated with status 1
```

Comment: Has it been freezing occasionally for the whole 2 years? Any updates, especially kernels, before it started? About the log, did it freeze right after 13:16:16, or thereabouts, 84 seconds after boot? That could just be the current sessions's log, previous one could be somewhere else (in /var/log/ ?), might have a kernel panic or something similar to <2839824> with some `?` characters, definitely stands out in a dmesg/syslog. Or it could've frozen "solid" with no messages too

Comment: Yep, I've always had that problem from the beginning, no other problems though.  This is from /var/log/syslog btw..  I copied it from the log after the laptop booted back up, so I can only guess that it froze at 13:15:39..  But even if it has frozen solid (seems so), wouldn't then still something bad have to have happened right before that? Unless it's a hardware issue, But I never had this problem on debian, which it was running before elementary

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `[   46.979256]` part is the seconds since boot that dmesg (or the kernel?) writes. I usually run live so when the rare crash occurs (yearly) I don't have logs to check (were in ram, wiped onreboot). Sometimes just straight to panic msgs, but a hard freeze doesn't even show those. Older logs might still  be there somewhere... I'm just guessing, but since Debian was fine,  maybe it's a kernel issue now? Could try booting with a different kernel (newer or older, maybe a "stable" one?) but search for how to boot a *previous/old kernel* first, just in case.

Comment: Actually an old computer used to crash more often when I used compiz, I think elementary OS has nice windows & graphics, so maybe try disabling hardware acceleration, or turn some graphic effects off (compositing)? A more basic window manager is an idea too

Comment: I don't know, I am on the latest kernel now, but I've had this problem for 2 years on every kernel released so far..  As for the hardware, I'm running a 3rd gen i5, with 6gb ram, geforce gt540m cuda 1gb, and an ssd, which is only half full so far.  Also it never seems to be under load at the time it freezes

Comment: Looks like no messages about the freeze... if the kernel were still "alive" I'd hope it would have printed something, and you could still use the "Magic SysRq" keys to sync & reboot with the keyboard (may have to enable them). Since you were updating the kernel the whole time it's probably not an easily fixed bug. I'm not too sure what to do, try disabling any hardware specific drivers (video seems especially prone), or conversely try finding some if there's none, or use a distro that doesn't freeze and install some ElementaryOS packages & see if they work ok?

Comment: What are these Magic keys you're talking about? I've already switched to different gpu drivers after reading some people had problems with nvidia, but it didn't help for me.. Anyway the strange thing about it is also that it doesn't freeze when the gpu is under load, but just randomly, like just now it froze while I had nothing open except for Leafpad.. Also I can't find anyone else having this problem with eOS, which makes me think it's either the ssd, ram, or cpu while the fact that debian running okay 2 years ago might've been a coincidence, I could try a different distro and test ram & cpu

Comment: Wikipedia has a good overview https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key . Could be a hardware problem, definitely test ram, could look for lint blocking air vents too or fans that have quit. Monitor temps (with `sensors`) if you can. At least trying some other distors live (with a USB or dvd) should leave your "main" drive alone too, or many iso's will boot from grub if you copy them & add the right entry too.

Comment: Thanks man, I never knew that was a thing, next time it happens I'll try it, if only i could predict when it happens, since it doesnt happen every day and it seems completely random. Also the heat seems fine most of the time, I've just reapplied all the thermal paste about 6 months ago

Comment: try asking on https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to give a silver bullet answer to a question like this since it's so broad but you would theoretically get there by working through the layers of your system(check out [this detailed break-down of an eOS distro](https://elementary.io/open-source)) down to the kernel to see what exactly is causing the problem. Consider this an answer to help you come to a more precise question. In the process you'll probably learn a lot about how your system works.

To begin, next time it freezes try [switching to a tty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481906/what-does-tty-stand-for). This is done with a keypress(`CTRL + ALT + F1 through F6`. If your function keys are usually used for volume, brightness control, etc. then you may need to include the `Fn` key in these combinations. If that's successful then I would start to suspect some part of your GUI. Once switched over, enter your user credentials and then you can try a myriad of methods to diagnose the source of the problem. A couple may be:

- Run the `top` command and look for a process(near the top of the list) that's consuming 100% CPU resources or a great amount of any other resource.
- Check the various layers of logs. If you're suspecting a GUI issue, start with the Xorg logs, which are the lowest level of "GUI", i.e. your desktop. Try checking if the X server is logging any events, for example. [Arch Wiki's directions on this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg#Troubleshooting) is pretty good. Namely, try checking Xorg.0.log and Xorg.1.log for lines that begin with `EE` or `WW` which indicate errors or warnings respectively.

To return to your GUI, hit `Ctrl + Alt + F7` (again, the `Fn` key might apply here).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make much sense, but removing `wingpanel-indicator-power` resolved the hangup problems for me.

```
sudo apt-get remove wingpanel-indicator-power
```

My system was not completely freezing like you reported, but I was having quick hangups, for example when opening a new tab in chrome.